# Knockout JS - Value of span

Tags: jquery, knockout-2.0

My application is MVC5; I am trying to get the value of Knockout span using the following:

```
<span id="total" data-bind="text: allImages().length"> </span>
```

I see 10 on the screen which is the correct value.

Tried to use:

```
var total = $('.total').text();
alert(total);
```

Don't get any value, also tried .val().

**Edit** 
I can get the value if I use this function:

```
   function getvalue() {
        var total = $('#total').text();
        $('#mytext').val(total);
        alert(total);
    }
```

Is there a way to get the value Onchange of span text?

Answer (score 2):

You need `$('#total')`, not `$('.total')`

`#total` finds that element by its ID, which is correct for your HTML span with that ID; `.total` means get by className, and there is no div in your code with that class, so it's correctly matching no elements.

Comment: Thank you, I tired # before and still don't get any value.